# php validate email extension type

Tags: php

This is my code to validate email, it works great but I want if the email does not end with a .mil it says invalid email

```
if (isset($_POST['update_email'])) {

        $email = escape($_POST['email']);

        if (empty($email)) {
            $errors[] = "Email Address Required.";
        }
        if (email_exists($email)) {
            $errors[] = "Email Address in use.";
        }

        if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
            $errors[] = "Invalid Email Address";
        }

        if (! empty($errors)) {

            echo validation_errors($errors[0]);
        } else {

   }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some example email inputs? The `filter_var` method should work for all emails, not just `.mil` ones

Comment: well first.last@branch.mil  branches theres army marines coast guard air force..  the end is .mil which is military

Comment: I see - misunderstood and thought you were saying that method didn't work. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a regular expression conditional statement

```
if (!preg_match('/\.mil$/', $email) {
    $errors[] = "Invalid Email Address";`
}
```

Or perhaps you can build this logic inside email_exists.